# Help making my pagination plugin better

Tags: plugins, jquery, pagination, ajax

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask for this kind of help since is not an actual question but hopefully I can learn a thing or two.

I'm developing a plugin (my first one) inspired in the [Infinite Scroll Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/), but instead of showing older posts when scrolling down, I'm showing them when you click a "Show more" link.

My intention is to make it public but I know there are a lot of things on it that I can improve before doing so, I tested it a bit in a couple themes and it worked fine but I'm not sure how it'll behave in the real world. Here's a link to it on github: https://github.com/javiervd/Click-and-Load-Pagination

Some concerns at the top of my head are:
- How to handle users including and external jQuery library instead of the WP one? I'm currently queuing WP's jQuery but I'm not sure how good is this.
- Simplicity? As I said this plugin is based on the Infinite Scroll Plugin so I used a similar but much simpler approach to set the options, hopefully this can be optimized as well.
- Best practices? This is my first "real" plugin I'm sure I'm not following the best practices out there :(

I hope some of you guys can help me, I'll make sure to mention everyone who does when I release it, feel free to fork/request pulls if you wish.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While asking for code review is fine (although not that popular) I think you might get much better feedback by asking about some of your "concerns" as separate and more specific questions.

Comment: I think you're right, I was hoping though that someone would point out stuff that I might have overlooked which I know I have :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here are some pointers:

- never run any meaningful code right from plugin body (especially don't start queuing jQuery **everywhere** like you do - that's asking for trouble), always do it at appropriate hooks;
- learn how to use `$default` argument in [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) will save you a lot of typing there;
- learn how to use [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) for reliable URL building to files;
- learn [`submit_button()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button), not critical but nifty;
- consider storing options in single array;
- if you use options you should implement uninstall to delete them.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rarst, I'll start refactoring some code didn't know about the `$default` argument in `get_option()`

Comment: I'm being a newb here but what do you mean by "never run any meaningful code right from plugin body" ?

Comment: @javiervd most of the time you should not do anything right in plugin file, hook to `init` (or whatever appropriate, depending on what you are doing) and do things in hooked function.